# Error 1292: Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00' for column 'password_changed_at' at row 1

Tags: mysql, go, orm, database-migration

I have a Gin and [upper/db](https://upper.io/v4/adapter/mysql/) MySQL ORM for the Rest API server. I have created a simple script to create the database and tables after "first deploy" or something like that. But I keep getting errors from SQL.

This is my User Model:

```golang
type User struct {
    ID                int64     `db:"id,omitempty" json:"id,omitempty"`
    Email             string    `db:"email" json:"email"`
    Password          string    `db:"password" json:"password,omitempty"`
    ProfileImage      string    `db:"profile_image" json:"profile_image"`
    PasswordChangedAt time.Time `db:"password_changed_at" json:"password_changed_at,omitempty"`
    CreatedAt         time.Time `db:"created_at" json:"created_at"`
}
```

And this is what my first user input looks like:

```golang
user := models.User{
        Email:     "admin@site.com.uy",
        Password:  "password",
        CreatedAt: time.Now(),
    }
```

I am getting errors from the database like:

> "sql: Scan error on column index 8, name "password_changed_at": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type  into type *time.Time"

Also got the error with "ProfileImage" etc.

This is my Users table creation:

```golang
_, err = db.Exec(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        profile_image VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '',
        password_changed_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL,
        created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )`)
```

I have tried changing the `password_changed_at` to `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` but it gives me another error:

> Error 1292: Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00' for column 'password_changed_at' at row 1

#### Edit:

I fixed that error by adding `omitempty` to `db` tag for `password_changed_at` like:

```golang
    PasswordChangedAt time.Time `db:"password_changed_at" json:"password_changed_at,omitempty"`.
```

But now, whenever I get a user I get the following error:

```json
{
  "error": "sql: Scan error on column index 8, name \"password_changed_at\": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type <nil> into type *time.Time"
}
```

Could you adjust the SQL code to create the users table for the desired model? Or indicate me any errors you see.

Comment: You do not specify the value for `password_changed_at`, hence DEFAULT should be used. Who sets zero datetime? I think this is ORM. Set the value explicitly, use autoutilizing, use trigger which sets the value...

Comment: [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Comment: @FanoFN that one I resolved it. But still, I didn't need to update `password_changed_at` since it should only be update once the password is updated. As a workaround to my new problem I am assiging a value anyway.

Comment: Let me understand it a bit here, which one of the operation returned error, `CREATE TABLE`, `INSERT` or `UPDATE`?

Answer (score 1):

This error is normally caused by trying to create two date field with different timestamp values. To fix this I just add the following query in the affected table.

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode global, @@SESSION.sql_mode session;
SET sql_mode = '';
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
```

Then you can try againg to write your CREATE table query